# Django built-in server stops receiving requests

Tags: python, django

I'm currently using django 1.5 with python 2.7.

After starting django with "./manage.py runserver", within a few minutes the server stops receiving requests. I can kill it and start it again, try another port, another host, nothing works, it just stops receiving the requests(nothing is logged to the terminal when I request a page and the browser just loads it forever).

I looked on the web and don't saw any mention to this problem; If there is any logs or information I can add to help me find what's the problem, just tell me.

-- Edit

I'm currently running arch linux, this is not my first project, any project doesn't work after the first time it stops, even tough I can run simple web servers with python and that works just fine.

Comment: That does sound weird, but you'll have to share some more information for us to help you. What os are you using? is this your first django project? Do you see this in a specific project or all of your projects? etc. etc. Anything you find relevant

Comment: @yuvi Thanks, I edited my question to add the information.

Comment: Does the server respond to requests at all?

Comment: @thebjorn When I first start it, yes, it works just fine and handle all the requests. After a few minutes it just stops receiving the requests, there's no record on the console that the request was made.

Comment: Sure it just hasn't gone into an infinite loop somehow or doing anything that would cause it to block on IO. Is it showing any activity in the process list?

Comment: I would suggest writing a middleware class that logs the start and end of the requests, so you can figure out what it was doing when it stopped.

Comment: @thebjorn It's probably not something related to specific requests, because OP mentions that this happens to all projects

Comment: Which database/db-library versions are you using?  I vaguely recall needing a specific set of MySQL libraries, but that was on a production server...